# Xamarin ios auto scroll view on input click jumps when a value entered

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've followed the following code to setup a view to auto scroll up when an input is selected so it isnt covered by a keyboard. 
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4994/is-there-something-in-xamarin-for-auto-scrolling-when-keyboard-show-and-hide

It works great until I start to actually enter a value. When I start to type on the keyboard the UI moves, either back to original or half the height of the text box.

What methods could be executing that force the UI to move? I'm overriding and debugging UpdateViewConstraints() and that is not getting fired and none of the events I added are either. I don't know where to go to debug this because I can't find what is moving the UI!

Any help would be great. I can start adding in code but it's almost exactly a copy of the link and I don't want to overly clutter the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
    CoreGraphics.CGRect keyboardBounds;
    NSObject keyboardShowObserver;
    NSObject keyboardHideObserver;
   public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    { 
     base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    keyboardShowObserver = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification, (notification) =>
        {
             NSValue nsKeyboardBounds = (NSValue)notification.UserInfo.ObjectForKey(UIKeyboard.BoundsUserInfoKey);
            keyboardBounds = nsKeyboardBounds.RectangleFValue;
            ScrollView.ContentSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(0, View.Frame.Height + keyboardBounds.Height);
            var Variation = FindFirstResponder(ScrollView).Frame.Bottom - View.Bounds.Height + keyboardBounds.Height;
            if (Variation > 0) { 
                            ScrollView.SetContentOffset(new CoreGraphics.CGPoint(0, Variation), false);
            }
            ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;
        });
 keyboardHideObserver = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification, (notification) =>
        {
            UIApplication.EnsureUIThread();
            ScrollView.ContentSize = new CoreGraphics.CGSize(0, View.Frame.Height - keyboardBounds.Height);
        });
}

public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
    {
base.ViewDidDisappear(animated);
        if (keyboardShowObserver != null)
        {
            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(keyboardShowObserver);
        }
        if (keyboardHideObserver != null)
        {
            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.RemoveObserver(keyboardHideObserver);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide any explanation of the code you posted or how it answers the original question? The question-asker raised specific questions that this code alone can't answer without a little explanation.